# converting links to python dictionary for d3.js interactive tree

Tags: python, algorithm, d3.js

I have links in hierarchical form like this.

```
root/Arts/
root/Arts/Literature/
root/Arts/Literature/Novels/
root/Arts/Literature/Comics/
root/Sports/
root/Sports/Football/
...
```

I want to plot them and visualize the tree but the tree goes very deep with too many links.
I am not able to view this tree more than 3 levels when using `pydot`/`graphviz`.

I want to convert this to a dictionary key value pairing with children
like this

```
[
{
  "name": "root",
  "parent": "null",
  "children": [
      {
        "name": "Arts",
        "parent": "root",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Literature",
            "parent": "Arts",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Novels",
                "parent": "Literature"
              },
              {
                "name": "Comics",
                "parent": "Literature"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Sports",
        "parent": "root",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Football",
            "parent": "Sports"
          }
         ]
       }
    ]
}
]
```

to plot this into a `d3.js` interactive tree

**EDIT**

This worked for me -

```
def add_to_tree(name, parent, start_tree):
    for x in start_tree:
        if x["name"] == parent:
            x["children"].append({"name":name, "parent":parent, "children":[]})
        else:
            add_to_tree(name, parent, x["children"])

def dic_converter_single_root(sorted_list):
    start_tree = [{"name":"root", "parent":"null", "children":[]}]
    for x in sorted_list:
        name = x.split('/')[-2]
        parent = x.split('/')[-3]
        add_to_tree(name, parent, start_tree)
```

Comment: Are you trying to do the data transformation in Python or JavaScript?  Have you attempted to code it yourself?

Comment: @Mark i'm trying to do this in python(not good with JavaScript). I'm having trouble figuring out the depth at which a particular object will be added as children.